# How to display the value of an array element or object property in PHP Heredoc syntax

Tags: php, arrays, object, heredoc

I'm having trouble displaying an array value inside a heredoc input field.  Here's a snippet of code:

```
class Snippet{
  protected $_user;
  protected $_class;
  protected $_messages;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->_user = $this->_class = NULL;
    $this->createUser();
  }

  public function createUser(){
    $keys = array('user_login','user_email');
    $this->_user = $this->_class = array_fill_keys($keys, '');
  }

  public function userErrors(){
    //by default give the login field autofocus
    $_class['user_login'] = 'autofocus';
  }


  public function getForm(){

  return <<<HTML
<form id='test' action='' method='post'>
$this->_messages    
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Testing Heredoc</legend>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for='user_login'>Username</label>
        <input  id='user_login' name='user_login' type='text' placeholder='Login name' value=$this->_user[user_login] $this->_class[user_login]>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
HTML;
  }
}
```

My output yields a labeled input box with the value displayed as `Array[user_login]`.
I can assign the array to separate variables and get the output I'm looking for, but this seems like an unnecessary waste.  PHP 5.3.5

Comment: Do yourself (or whoever is going to maintain that code) a favor and separate your business logic from the presentation. HTML output intermingled with PHP logic is a quagmire, heredoc or not.

Comment: Try using PHP's templating instead of HEREDOC, it would be simpler.

Comment: too right you are... separated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap your array variable inside curly braces `{}` like this

```
value="{$this->_user['user_login']} {$this->_class['user_login']}"
```

[Here](http://blog.nazdrave.net/?p=626) is a nice article on this.

**From the article**

> Unfortunately, PHP doesn’t provide any direct means for calling
>   functions or outputting expression results in HEREDOC strings. The
>   problem here is that, unless the thing in the curly braces starts with
>   a dollar sign, it can’t be recognized by PHP as something to be
>   replaced.